# turn off redirection to /dev/null

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

within a bash script, the following line

```
 somecommand 2>/dev/null
```

directs error output (FD2, stderror) from somecommand to /dev/null, but also apparently directs stderror from every subsequent line of the script to same.  How do I "turn off" this redirection in order to get error messages resulting from subsequent commands within the script?

Comment: Is this part of the script you speak of or it's the whole script?

Comment: ... that should only happen if `somecommand` is actually `exec`

Comment: @steeldriver what if you did [redirected bash_xtracefd to /dev/null](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212124/what-are-the-consequences-of-redirecting-bash-xtracefd-to-dev-null?noredirect=1&lq=1) how would one turn it off?

Comment: @Fuseteam I followed your link chain but I'm still not clear exactly what you did or what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @steeldriver i suppressed the output of autocd  by redirecting BASH_XTRACEFD to /dev/null bu in case there is some unintended consequence from doing that i would like to "turn off the redirection to /dev/null" without needing to open a new terminal

Comment: @Fuseteam sorry I don't know anything about that - you will have to wait for someone to answer [your question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212124/what-are-the-consequences-of-redirecting-bash-xtracefd-to-dev-null)

Comment: @steeldriver ah sure but the consequences of the redirection is my question, what about the question the op is asked? a way to "turn off redirection to /dev/null" would be useful to work around any possible consequence, no?

Comment: @Fuseteam unless the OP actually used `exec 2>/dev/null` then all they did was a one-time redirection of the stderr of `somecommand` - there is nothing to "turn off". That's likely why the question remains unanswered.

Comment: @steeldriver so exec {BASH_XTRACEFD|>/dev/null is a one time thing?